# Castor and JAXB Marshaller

Tags: java, jaxb, castor

Currently I am using Castor framework to marshall the object into xml file it work greats

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter("D:/out.xml");
Marshaller.marshal(test, writer);
```

But now I am using javax.xml.bind to do the same thing.

```
            Writer writer = new FileWriter("D:/out.xml");
        JAXBContext context =
            JAXBContext.newInstance(test.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(test, writer);
```

Then I hits this error message :

unable to marshal type "package1.Testing" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [`XmlRootElement`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) annotation and you won't get the error anymore. This should be added to the top-level or "root" class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you roughly explain to me why using castor is okay but jaxb need to add in XmlRootElement

Comment: It's just semantics. The Castor and JAXB API's are different and JAXB requires the annotation whereas Castor doesn't.

Comment: Does it mean JAXB need to know which class to look at so in my Testing file i have to put in @XmlRootElement?

Comment: The class that is "test" is your example should have @XmlRootElement.

Comment: I know to add in the @XmlRootElement just want to know the reason why need to add in. Thanks for your answer I solved the problem

Comment: The reason is because that's how JAXB figures out name of root element. This is only needed for root element since properties use field/getter/setter name to determine element name; but this is not available for root. I guess Castor defaults to using class name or soemthing else, but JAXB requires explicit definition.